# Exception in "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety

I appologise in advance for this question possibly being hard to interpret, but I'm trying to include the minimum information necessary (I doubt you want to be reading through 10 different classes looking for the error)

I have been making a simple(ish) application in java, using swing for the GUI. Currently I have a JTable, JList and a JButton. When a **row** is double clicked in the table, it is added to the list. When the **button** is clicked, a customised fileVisitor walks through a (currently hard-coded) directory and populates the table with the files it was finding. The list does nothing so far. This all worked as expected.

However, when the button is clicked, the whole application locks up for the ~15s it takes the fileVisitor to run. This is fine if a bit irritating. When the file tree walk ends, the application responds again (and the table updates all rows at once).

So I decided to put the Files.walkFileTree call in its own thread. At first this appeared to be effective, as each file was added to the table model it was reflected in the table (that was set to call revalidate on a model change). However, if I double clicked an item while the file tree walk was in progess, it would hang with the message: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

After reading up on swing a bit, I assumed it was due to my editing the table model from a thread that was not the AWT dispatch thread, and promptly put the lines that edit the table model in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable) block. However, this did not fix the issue. Weirdly (or possibly not, it seems weird to me), sometimes a double-click works, and it's only after 2 or 3 attempts that I cause the crash.

My question is: what can be causing this? I can't see anything else obviously wrong, and all my googling points to Swings lack of thread-safety, and using the AWT dispatch thread (which I thought was what invokeLater does). Anyone know what's wrong?

P.S. sorry again if anything's unclear, and that it's so long :P

Comment: Yes, this is likely a threading issue, that you're still making Swing calls off of the event dispatch thread. Where? hard to say without code. Are you using a SwingWorker to do your background processing? If so, are you using its publish/process method pair to communicate interim results to the EDT? I second trash's recommendation -- if you're still stuck, create and post an SSCCE.

Comment: Your concern is well-meant, but the burden falls on you to provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I am not using SwingWOrker - I have in fact only just encountered the class (a response to the same question asked elswhere was to look at it). I'm reading up on it now

Comment: To reiterate an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is not your whole program and not a snippet of your program. Rather it's a completely new very small program that runs, compiles, and demonstrates your problem, but has no unnecessary  code unrelated to the problem. Check out the link please.

Comment: I believe that when the model events are fired they are fired on the same thread as the model...

Comment: @pst -- they should, but coders can call model methods off of the EDT if they're not careful.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand the desire for an SSCCE, I'm trying to type one up now. However it's not a small thing. I'll update if I can get one to work (and if SwingWorker does not provide an answer)

Comment: For reference, please cite the "the same question asked elsewhere."

Comment: @trashgod On Google+; one of my friends told me to look up Swing Worker on the oracle tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html <-- reading through it now

Comment: Got it. Rather than putting the file walk in a thread putting it in a SwingWorker fixed it. Thanks for helping (the comments gave me some ideas).

Comment: consider to put your solution into an answer and accept it - then it's easier for future readers to find

Comment: @kleopatra I was trying too but I had to wait to be able to answer my own question :P

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems it turns out:
1) I was using a thread for my file tree walk rather than a swing worker doInBackground;
2) my double click code was actually producing a null pointer, but only if you got the timing right while the table was updating, I've fixed that now too. Thanks for looking.